# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest on running this code as testNg

Tags: java, testng, appium-ios

```
package testgoogleapp;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

/**
 A test to demonstrate the automation on Safari browser using Appium [the open source tool]
*/
public class NewTest {
 WebDriver wd;

 @BeforeTest
 public void beforeTest() throws MalformedURLException { //set capabilities required
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1");
  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "safari");
  wd = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);//instantiate driver
  wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }

 @Test
 public void testSearchPage() throws InterruptedException {
  wd.get("https://www.google.co.in");
  WebElement serachField = wd.findElement(By.name("q"));
  serachField.sendKeys("Pooja Shah Selenium youtube");
  serachField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  System.out.println(wd.getCurrentUrl());
 }

 @AfterTest
 public void afterTest() {
  //wd.close();
 }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /private/var/folders/j1/tsq8g74x0730d7523hmm5rch0000gn/T/testng-eclipse-2007236291/testng-customsuite.xml

[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/Default suite/Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/Default suite exists: true
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.substituteMobilePlatform(Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:37)
    at testgoogleapp.NewTest.beforeTest(NewTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:592)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest afterTest
SKIPPED: testSearchPage

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@880ec60: 49 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@7e0ea639: 13 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/junitreports/TEST-testgoogleapp.NewTest.xml
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/junitreports exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@2acf57e3: 4 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/testng-failed.xml
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/Default suite/testng-failed.xml
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/Default suite exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 4 ms
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite/toc.html
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite/Default test.properties
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite/index.html
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite/main.html
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite/groups.html
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite/classes.html
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite/reporter-output.html
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite/methods-not-run.html
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite/testng.xml.html
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/Default suite exists: true
[Utils] Attempting to create /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old/index.html
[Utils]   Directory /Users/akifhazarvi/Documents/workspace/testgoogleapp/test-output/old exists: true
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@7a79be86: 15 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@17f6480: 6 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can replace strings by their constants: `MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME/PLATFORM_VERSION/DEVICE_NAME`.

Then, you must have, at least, Appium 2.0 in your classpath (and NO lower versions).